# How to create one nuget package for multiple version of the same assembly

Tags: tfs, nuget, version

I was wondering if there is a way to create one nuget package for multiple version of an assembly (i.e. dll v1.0.0 and dll v1.0.1), so that each version will show in the version drop down option in nuget? Or will I have to create separate packages for each version?(which is what I've have so far)

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want environment-specific packages? You should be building your software once and deploying that version progressively through an environment pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

`How to set up nuget versions for multiple environment.` Guess the nuget versions in your question stands for the package version not the version of `nuget.exe`  such 3.3, 3.5 , 4.0. If it stands for `nuget.exe` version, have no idea why you need to use different `nuget.exe` versions for multiple environment.

You could  version the packages as you need. A way to cross multiple environments is  setting up 3 different NuGet repositories such as:

> - Development repository: A file share that all developers have    read-only access to. The file share has a space for NuGet packages
>     and one for the matching NuGet symbol packages. Only the build server 
>     (and the build engineers) have write access to this repository.
> - QA repository: Another file share similar to the Development    repository.
> - Production repository: A private instance of the Klondike NuGet    server which serves as the NuGet and symbol server for all NuGet
>     packages (and their sources) which are allowed to be used in
>     production builds.

More details please refer this similar question: [NuGet Server for multiple enviornments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34161517/nuget-server-for-multiple-enviornments)

Comment: Oh I'm not talking about different version of nuget.exe, sorry for the confusion. So basically, set up 3 different nuget server for each environment? and do I push each package on all 3 servers? Is this the best option or are there other ways? I'm trying to come up with the best model to present on the best way to incorporate nuget at my work.